# Using proxy with ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, proxy

I am using ArcGIS with JavaScript API and I am trying to get a proxy since some functionality requires specifically to install and set up a proxy. I have looked at the manual but it is a little bit hard for me to follow, I am a new developer and am using github as a server.

Comment: post the code where you're stuck , we'll see !

Answer (score 2):

GitHub doesn't let you host server side applications, so you cannot run your proxy there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718649/how-to-publish-a-website-made-by-node-js-to-github-pages

Comment: So what would you suggest to use?

Comment: for your initial development you'll need to run a local web server.  later you'll need a real web server on the public internet.  these days more people use cloud services like AWS than administer their own physical machines.  what exactly do you even need the proxy for?

Comment: thanks for the help. I am learning Arcgis Api using javascript and when I use for spatial query for the data that is on arcgis server, the information is passed in the URL string, which has a limit of 2,048 characters. So I need to have a proxy on my computer to get around this problem. The documentation give some info about installing the proxy:                       https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html                          but I was not able to make it work,

Comment: a proxy isn't necessary if both your instance of ArcGIS Server and the browsers consuming your application support CORS.  if not, you'll need one.